# What is the equivalent of Python Pandas value_counts in SQL?

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I learned python and pandas before SQL, so this question is a bit basic.

For example, I have a `type` column with values like 1, 2, 3.

Then when I do df['type'].value_counts, I can get the statistics of the `type`, maybe something like

```
1: 1000 rows
2: 220 rows
3: 100 rows
```

I want to know What is the equivalent in SQL? I believe it should be something about group_by and count?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want to know how many times each value occurs in a column, use:

```
SELECT type, count(*)
FROM table
GROUP BY type
```

Comment: How could it be normalized? e.g. get the values in percentages. Do we need a subquery?

Comment: I solved it like this:

SELECT
    status, 100*CAST(COUNT(* ) AS FLOAT) / (SELECT COUNT(* ) FROM emails)
FROM
    emails
GROUP BY 
    status

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT type, count(1) as num_types
FROM table
GROUP BY type
```

will return the equivalent row counts.